# Step by step developing AUTOSAR's Software Component

Tags: development-environment, autosar

I'm a new learner about the AUTOSAR and already understand about summary of AUTOSAR Architecture. I have read AUTOSAR_TR_Methodology.pdf as my starting point to developing AUTOSAR's sofware components (SWC). For another information, I should get the "system extract" from the main organization and I will add my SWC into it. In that document, the task that I have to do to develop SWC described one by one as a whole process, but not in sequence. So my question is, after I got the system extract what the task that required to do to make SWCs? It will be great if the tools is mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The system extract usually contains software-components, albeit usually in form of so called compositions (in AUTOSAR lingo: CompositionSwComponentType). These compositions come with defined PortPrototypes which in turn are typed by PortInterfaces.
2. The task of the designer of an application software-component (technically speaking: an ApplicationSwComponentType) is to connect to the PortPrototypes define on the composition level and then specify the internal behavior (SwcInternalBehavior) that formally defines the internal structure of a software-component. On this basis the function of the software-component can be implemented.
3. A software-component itself consists of the formal specification (serialized in the ARXML format) and the corresponding C code that implements the actual function of the software-component.
4. There are tons of tools out there to develop AUTOSAR software-components. Most of these are commercial, and require a license. On top of that, the toolchain to be applied for a given project is in many cases predefined and you may not be able to select your tools freely.
5. If you seriously want to dive into AUTOSAR I'd strongly advise taking a class offered by the various tool vendors, preferably a class held by the tool vendor selected for a given actual ECU project.

Comment: To create SWC Internal Behavior are always using one of AAT?

Comment: number 5 is big problem, my boss doesn't let me taking a class. As always, the money problem I think.

Comment: No offense, but I doubt that it will be possible to gain enough skills to seriously participate in an AUTOSAR-based development project by asking questions on Stack Overflow. SO can help to fill some gaps or set you up in the right direction. But let's face it, AUTOSAR is **very** complex and you are barely beginning to scratch at the surface.

Comment: The only advice that may help at this point is to stop reading the AUTOSAR methodology document and dive into the basics first. If you are interested in developing AUTOSAR software-components, go read the documents "TPS Software Component Template" and the "SWS RTE".

Comment: Thank you for your opinion and I totally agree with you. But my company thoughts that AUTOSAR can be learned just by read the documentation and join several seminars. As a executor, it was really difficult for sure. Yes, I have been reading SoftwareComponentTemplate and RTE, but just part that possibly match with my demand like Runnable Entity, Port, and InterrRunnableVariable.

Comment: Yes you right about "No offense, but I doubt that it will be possible to gain enough skills to seriously participate in an AUTOSAR-based development project by asking questions on Stack Overflow". I'm just too desperate so I decided ask on stackoverflow, it because there are no tools in my company and there are no AUTOSAR experts in my company. Thanks a lot for you who answer my question, I'm really appreciated this.